# Google Maps Android permission denied

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm facing google map authentication inconsistency problems whereby when i run my app it connect and works perfectly however when I rerun it again it does not connect and throws permission denied error. This issue persists for a long time and luckily again it resumes connection. I've tried to check my google api key and it appears to be fine since sometimes the app authenticates successfully.

Below is my code:

```
public class PlacesAutoCompleteActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        View.OnClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback,
        LocationListener {
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private boolean executeOnStart = false;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_INDIA = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(-0, 0), new LatLng(0, 0));
    public GoogleMap mMap;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    private String mapAddress = null;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Button checkAvailability;
    private StringBuilder sb = null;
    private EditText mAutocompleteView;
    private Geocoder geocoder;
    private MarkerOptions markerOptions;
    private LatLng latLng;
    private boolean availabilityCheck = false;
    private Marker marker;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
    private PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter mAutoCompleteAdapter;
    PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item;
    String featureName, locality, countryName;
    String placeId;
    ImageView delete;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private boolean allowEditTextChangeListener = true; // disable google maps autocomplete when user clicks on map to avoid fetching location of chosen place
    private LatLng pos;
    static boolean invalidLocation = false; // this value confirms whether we are able to deliver to users location
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);


        mAutocompleteView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_places);

        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(PlacesAutoCompleteActivity.this);

        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);

        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        delete = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cross);

        mAutoCompleteAdapter = new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.searchview_adapter,
                mGoogleApiClient, BOUNDS_INDIA, null);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAutoCompleteAdapter);
       // mRecyclerView.setLayoutFrozen(true);
        delete.setOnClickListener(this);

        if (allowEditTextChangeListener) {
            Log.d("allowEditTextChangz1",allowEditTextChangeListener + "");
            mAutocompleteView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                          int count) {
                    Log.d("allowEditTextChangz1","jo");
                    if (!s.toString().equals("") && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                        Log.d("allowEditTextChangzQ",s.toString());
                        mAutoCompleteAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                    } else if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                        checkAvailability.setEnabled(false);
                        checkAvailability.setAlpha(0.3f);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e(Constants.PlacesTag, Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED);
                    }

                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                              int after) {

                }

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
        }
        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        item = mAutoCompleteAdapter.getItem(position);
                        placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);

                        PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                                .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
                        placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                                if (places.getCount() == 1) {
                                    mAutoCompleteAdapter.clear();
                                    mAutocompleteView.setText("");
                                    String country = "";

                                    try {
                                        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(places.get(0).getLatLng().latitude,
                                                places.get(0).getLatLng().longitude, 1);
                                        sb = new StringBuilder();
                                        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                                            android.location.Address address = addresses.get(0);

                                            featureName = address.getFeatureName();
                                            locality = address.getLocality();
                                            countryName = address.getCountryName();


                                            Log.d("featureName ",  featureName + "||" +
                                                    locality +"||" + countryName);
                                            if (featureName == null) {
                                                mapAddress = address.getLocality() + " " + address.getCountryName();
                                            } else if (locality == null) {
                                                mapAddress = address.getFeatureName() + ", " + address.getCountryName();
                                            } else if (countryName == null) {
                                                mapAddress = address.getFeatureName() + ", " + address.getLocality();
                                            } else {
                                                mapAddress = address.getFeatureName() + ", " + address.getLocality() + " " + address.getCountryName();
                                                country = address.getCountryName();
                                                Log.d("counttryy", "sasa"+country);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        Log.d("mpaddress", "kaka "+mapAddress + "||" + country);

                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                            .target(places.get(0).getLatLng())      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
                                            .zoom(12)                   // Sets the zoom
                                            .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                                            .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                                            .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder

                                    marker.remove(); // remove any marker from maponclick or maponlonclick
                                    marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(places.get(0).getLatLng())
                                            .title("My Location"));
                                    mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
                                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                                    if (countryName.toLowerCase().equals("kenya")){
                                        availabilityCheck = true;
                                        checkAvailability.setEnabled(true);
                                        confirmPosition();
                                    } else {
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Constants.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
        );

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.maps_close);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("close", "close");
                if (mAutoCompleteAdapter.getItemCount() != 0){
                    mAutoCompleteAdapter.clear();
                }
                mAutocompleteView.setText("");
            }
        });

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
             mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation = location;

        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }
        //mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        final Double lat = location.getLatitude();
        final Double lng = location.getLongitude();
        Log.d("LATLANGz", lat + "|" + lng);
        latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Positionn");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera_main
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));


        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }


        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                android.location.Address address = addresses.get(0);

                String featureName = address.getFeatureName();
                String locality = address.getLocality();
                String countryName = address.getCountryName();

                System.out.println("featureName " + featureName + "||" + locality +"||" + countryName);
                if (featureName == null) {
                    mapAddress = address.getLocality() + " " + address.getCountryName();
                } else if (locality == null) {
                    mapAddress = address.getFeatureName() + ", " + address.getCountryName();
                } else if (countryName == null) {
                    mapAddress = address.getFeatureName() + ", " + address.getLocality();
                } else {
                    mapAddress = address.getFeatureName() + ", " + address.getLocality() + " " + address.getCountryName();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("mpaddress " + mapAddress + "||" );
            mAutocompleteView.setText(mapAddress);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2> "+mapAddress + lat + lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }});
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.v("Google API Callback", "Connection Suspended");
        Log.v("Code", String.valueOf(i));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.v("Google API Callback","Connection Failed");
        Log.v("Error Code", String.valueOf(connectionResult.getErrorCode()));
        Toast.makeText(this, Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v==delete){
            mAutocompleteView.setText("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()){
            Log.v("Google API","Connecting");
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            Log.v("Google API","Dis-Connecting");
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d("permission","permission");
            // Asking user if explanation is needed
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


            } else {
                Log.d("permission2","permission2");
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
//                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        if (isNetworkAvailable() == true){
            if (isLocationEnabled(getApplicationContext())){
                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    checkLocationPermission();
                }
                // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
                SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            } else{
                Display.displaySnackbar(getApplicationContext(), linearLayout, "YOUR GPS IS CURRENTLY DISABLED");
                showLocationDialog();
            }
        } else {
            Display.displaySnackbar(getApplicationContext(), linearLayout, "YOU ARE CURRENTLY OFFLINE");
            showInternetDialog();
        }

    }

    public void showInternetDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Please turn on mobile network or Wi-Fi in Settings.")
                .setTitle("WIFI Disabled")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Settings",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        }
                )
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                PlacesAutoCompleteActivity.this.finish();
                            }
                        }
                );
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null;
    }

    public static boolean isLocationEnabled(Context context) {
        int locationMode = 0;
        String locationProviders;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
            try {
                locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);

            } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            return locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;

        }else{
            locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
            return !TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders);
        }
    }

    public void showLocationDialog(){
        executeOnStart = true;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.gps_not_found_message)
                .setTitle(R.string.gps_not_found_title)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Settings",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        }
                )
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dg, int id) {
                                // dialog.dismiss();
                                // SignIn.dialog.dismiss();
                                PlacesAutoCompleteActivity.this.finish();

                            }
                        }
                );
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: can you put the logcat message here when you get permission denied..

Comment: let me fetch them but one of the items i observed in the logcat is the message "GMS http client unavailable, use old client"

Comment: 10-05 12:56:01.120 3648-4959/? D/GameManagerService: there is not sem_perfomance_mode on setting
10-05 12:56:01.133 3817-3817/? D/permission: permission
10-05 12:56:01.134 3817-3817/? D/permission2: permission2
10-05 12:56:01.134 3817-3817/? W/Activity: Can reqeust only one set of permissions at a time

Comment: it seems like you are requesting multiple permission at one time..

Comment: programmatically and on the manifest file?

Comment: what OS you are running..?

Comment: it hink programmatically..

Comment: Please do not comment comments asking for additional information or clarification: update your post (here: question).

Comment: When I install the app the first time and allow permissions manually, google maps does not initialize i.e it shows the default map without my current location but when I run the app the second time the map initializes and shows my current location